# How To Create "Empty" <Label> Tag Without Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, label

I'm creating a simple calculator using Javascript and already have the Javascript code complete. I need to create three labels: "First Number", "Second Number", and a Sum label, but I do not want "Sum" to show up to the left of the text box. Here is my current HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="calculator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<label>Sum:</label>
<input type="text" id="sum" disabled="disabled">
<br>
<label>First Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstNumber">    
<br>
<label>Second Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="secondNumber">
<br>

<div>
<input type="button" id="calc" value="Calculate">
<input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
</div>

</section>
</body>

</html>
```

When I delete the word "Sum" from the label tag, the text box shifts to the left - I need it to stay lined up with the other two text boxes. Is there any way to keep the text box where it is without entering anything in the label tag? Thanks for the help.

CSS:

```
label {
float: left;
width: 11em;
text-align: right; 
}
```

How do I create another element in CSS just for that particular label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

html :

```
<body>
<section>
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<label class="sum">Sum:</label>
<input type="text" id="sum" disabled="disabled">
<br>
<label>First Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstNumber">    
<br>
<label>Second Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="secondNumber">
<br>

<div>
<input type="button" id="calc" value="Calculate">
<input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
</div>

</section>
</body>
```

css:

```
label {
float: left;
width: 11em;
text-align: right; 
}
.sum {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a fixed width for all your label elements using CSS such as:

```
    label {width: 150px; display: inline-block; }
```

the label element should then stay the same regardless of the text inside.

Comment: Since I already have CSS for the labels, how do I create another CSS element just for that particular label?

Comment: You just need to add the `display: inline-block` declaration.  Without this the labels default to inline display and only take up the width of their content.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class, say `name`, to the target `label` elements and then add the following to your CSS:

```
.name {
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

```css
.name {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  background-color:#eee;
}
```

```html
<section>
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<label class="name">Sum:</label>
<input type="text" id="sum" disabled="disabled">
<br>
<label class="name">First Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstNumber">    
<br>
<label class="name">Second Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="secondNumber">
<br>

<div>
<input type="button" id="calc" value="Calculate">
<input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML table. Fastest and simplest way to achieve it, I think.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="sum" disabled="disabled"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>First Number:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="firstNumber"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```